# How to disable quarkus dev mode?

Tags: quarkus

After a CLI application exits, on prod profile, i'd like it to go back to the shell instead of re-prompting the dev mode ("Press [space] to restart, [e] to edit command line args...")

Also would not need the "Press [h] for more options>" on startup.

Would it be possible to get quarkus "dev mode" totally out of the way in prod?

Comment: How are you starting the application? You're saying "in prod", so that's something like `mvn clean package` followed by `java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`, right? Because if you're doing `mvn quarkus:dev`, you're literally asking for dev mode and not doing a "prod" run.

Comment: @Ladicek That is the way to go, but not sure how to solve it. Yes, when using `java -jar ...` quarkus uses normal launch mode, but when it is ran using `java -cp ... MainClass`, it uses develoment launch mode instead. Unfortunatelly, maven appassembler plugin uses `java -cp`, so i'll probably need to write my own launch script :/

Answer (score 0):

> Description:

Add a configuration value/switch to disable the GRPC server in dev mode

At the moment there is no way to disable starting of the GRPC server in dev mode. For instance if only the client is used it is weird to have to assign a random port to the GRPC server to solve port collision for instance from a real GRPC server. So I don't really know if this is an actual feature request or a small bug.

> Implementation ideas:

Have a configuration value which disables the starting of the server, e.g.:

```
quarkus.grpc.server.enable
```